# Handling HTTP/2 GOAWAY in okhttp4

Tags: okhttp, http2

I am using `okhttp4 4.9.0` to send push notifications to APNs Http/2 server.
The call to `APNs` is synchronous.

The online documentation from [Apple](https://apple.co/3oBLMoB) has the following:

> If APNs decides to terminate an established HTTP/2 connection, it
> sends a GOAWAY frame

How do I handle this in okhttp4?

```
try {
    okHttpClient.newCall(request).execute().use { response -> println(response.code)  }
} catch(ioException: IOException) {
    //Is this the place to handle GOAWAY?          
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In practice you'll never need to worry about GOAWAY frames with OkHttp. If one is received it'll just create a new connection on the next request.

Comment: Worth noting that we drop the usefully specific error message that APNs sends because // TODO: log the debugData

Comment: Thank you @jesse-wilson. Is it documented somewhere? Pls send me link to it.